# Remove all the <p> or <ol> or all HTML elements after a particular heading until next heading

Tags: xpath

I want to remove all the html tags from document node after including the heading satisfying  a particular condition till new heading elements tag.

Eg: I want to Remove heading with id="notes" and all subsequent html tags until new heading tag comes. This pattern can be anywhere in the html page.
Input:

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Notes">Notes</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a title="Edit section: Notes" href="/w/index.php?title=Microsoft_HoloLens&amp;action=edit&amp;section=9">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2> 
<div class="reflist" style="list-style-type: decimal;">
<div class="mw-references-wrap">
<ol class="references">
<li id="cite_note-19"><span class="mw-cite-backlink"><b><a href="#cite_ref-19"><span class="cite-accessibility-label">Jump up </span>^</a></b></span> <span class="reference-text">See also: <a title="3D audio effect" href="/wiki/3D_audio_effect">3D audio effect</a>, <a title="Virtual surround" href="/wiki/Virtual_surround">virtual surround</a>, <a title="Psychoacoustics" href="/wiki/Psychoacoustics">psychoacoustics</a></span></li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
<p>3D applications, or "holographic" applications, use Windows Holographic APIs. Microsoft recommends <a title="Unity (game engine)" href="/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)">Unity</a> engine and <a title="Vuforia Augmented Reality SDK" href="/wiki/Vuforia_Augmented_Reality_SDK">Vuforia</a> to create 3D apps for HoloLens, but it's also possible for a developer to build their own engine using <a title="DirectX" href="/wiki/DirectX">DirectX</a> and <a title="Windows API" href="/wiki/Windows_API">Windows APIs</a>.<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-62"><a href="#cite_note-62">[61]</a></sup></p>
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="References">References</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a title="Edit section: References" href="/w/index.php?title=Microsoft_HoloLens&amp;action=edit&amp;section=10">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
```

Output should be something like this:

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="References">References</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a title="Edit section: References" href="/w/index.php?title=Microsoft_HoloLens&amp;action=edit&amp;section=10">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
```

Comment: What do you mean *remove*? `XPath` expression can only *return* required output, but not *remove* non-desired nodes from source. Clarify the issue and share your current code

Comment: i do not want to select non desired nodes. Here non desired nodes are heading tags  with a  particular id and all the subsequent tags until next heading tags.